# SQLite cause XamlParseException when executing ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

Today I tried to use SQLite database with my small WPF application, but I keep getting `XamlParseException was unhandled`. By taking out lines of code, I managed to notice that `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`causes the exception. In the rest, the SQLite connection seems working and also creating the database file.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Vitas\Desktop\TimeCounter.sqlite");
    conn.Open();
    string commandText = "CREATE TABLE  [EmpInfo]";
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a definition of fields when creating the table. Example:

```
string commandText = "CREATE TABLE [EmpInfo] (EmpId int)";
```

Ref: [Create table syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Comment: hm...I guess I got a bit messed up to miss it. Thank  you.